# Build android game by Unity and the game not running on android 4.0.3

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm building a game for android platform by using Unity, but the problem is I test my game on my phone with 4.0.3 android operator version and the game not running correctly,can anyone help?

Comment: can you provide what are the build setting you're using when creating the apk and how are you deploying it ?

Comment: I have seclected the android 2.1.3 minimum API level and the game still did not running, but my game is running now, after I create new project and copy all the game objects and script from old one to it!